# cal fragment from another module

Tags: android, android-fragments, module

I have a module named `editormodule` which I have a list of fragments and activities in it. let's say they are named (`fragment.MapFragment`) and  (`activity.EditActivity`).  Here is my EditActivity

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="fragment.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/actionbar"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/bottombar"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

When I start editActivity from my app (com.mobile.app.Main2Activity) it says

`com.mobile.app.Main2Activity.fragment.MapFragment` does not exist. In fact, It is located in the module, not in the app.

things that I have already done:
- I have added the module into apps dependencies
- I have added EditActivity to manifist.xml file
- My app only includes an activity without any extra fragments which could make possible conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

In the XML you need the class and not the name. According to your XML try to replace the fragment section with the following:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.mobile.app.fragment.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
```

**Edit:**
The class attribute must include the class path (including the whole package) of your fragment class.

**Edit2:** It is a good style to call in the onCreateView the layout like the following (in Kolin:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_your_layout, container, false)
    return view
}
```

Comment: Hi, In fact `com.mobile.app` is class path of my app and `fragment.Mapfragment` is class path of `Mapfragment` which is in my `module`. `com.mobile.app.fragment.MapFragment` says that android is looking for MapFragmet in app not in module

Comment: Can you please give me some more information about edit2?

Comment: Normaly you must provide any layout for your Fragment. Set the layout in this overriden method like descriped.